# Include Products in Magento Category by Search Query and/or Product Attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am building a new Magento store and would like to create product categories by query, without having to manually add each product to the category. For example, I would like to create a category titled "Small Shirts" which automatically displays all of my products that have the attribute size "Small." Or create another category called "Red Shirts" which displays all the products that have the word "red" in the title. Is there anyway to automate this so that I do not need to manually add each product to the category?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
 $products = array();
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('size','small')->getAllIds();
 foreach ($collection as $c){
      $products[$c]='0'; // 0 is the position, you can change this here if you want.
 }
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(YOURID);
 $category->setPostedProducts($products)->save();
```

Of course you can combine and create your category instead of load it if your script is supposed to create category before fill them with products.

Comment: Thanks for this response. Is there any way to do this from the Magento admin (without dealing with code) in a way that it will automatically include any new products with the set attribute as well? I am surprised I have not been able to find any working plugin that offers this fairly simple capability.

Comment: No, in the backend you can only do this with existing columns from the product grid (in the category edition page under Category Products). 

But you can override this grid to have more column filterable to populate quickly, but it will not be automatic. You'll need to set new product by hand in new categories.